# Модальное окно после цикла if

Tags: php, wordpress, bootstrap

Здравствуйте. На сайте есть форма, находящаяся в модальном окне: поле ввода, заполняемое пользователем и кнопка отправить.

```
<form id="transferCase-form" action=""  method="post">
<p><input class="paidtext" type="text" id="bTC" placeholder="" name="from_case" /></p>
<p><input class="btn-cr" type="submit" value="" id="transfetFrom" name="trans" /></p>
<p><input class="btn-cr" type="submit" value="" id="transfetFromAll" name="transall" /></p>
</form>
```

И обработчик, находится на этой же странице:

```
if (isset($_POST['trans'])) {  
                        if(isset($_POST["from_case"]) && $_POST["from_case"] != "") {
                            $from_case = (float) htmlspecialchars($_POST["from_case"]);
                            unset($_POST["from_case"]);
                            if ($from_case <= 100):
                                /*операции*/
                                header('Location: http://cryptozep.com/dashboard/');
                                exit;
                            else: echo 
                                "<script type='text/javascript'>
                                    $(document).ready(function() {

                                    if(window.location.href.indexOf('#myModal')) {
                                        $('#myModal').modal('show');
                                    }

                                    });
                                </script>"; 
                            endif;
                            $from_case = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (isset($_POST['transall'])) {
                        /*другие операции*/
                    }
```

В случае ошибки должно выплывать модальное окно, но после перезагрузки страницы, оно появляется снова и форма не обновляется, а отправляет данные снова.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно поменять или в какую сторону смотреть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обратите внимание на `$from_case`, я не вижу, что вы ей присваиваете какое-то значение.
Так же, после обновления страницы, значение `$_POST` не меняется. Тоесть после использования переменной, вы должны ее удалить (`unset($_POST['from_case'])`)

UPDATE:

```
if (isset($_POST['trans'])) {
    if(isset($_POST["from_case"]) && $_POST["from_case"] != "") {
        $from_case = (float) htmlspecialchars($_POST["from_case"]);
        unset($_POST["from_case"]);
        print "<h1>from_case: ".$from_case."<h1>"; //это для проверки значения. Вдруг там что-то другое
        if ($from_case <= 100):
            /*операции*/
            header('Location: http://');
            exit;
        else: echo 
            "<script type='text/javascript'>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    if(window.location.href.indexOf('#myModal')) {
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                }
                });
            </script>";
        endif; 
        $from_case = 0;   
    }
}
else if (isset($_POST['transall'])) {
    /*другие операции*/
}
```

NEW UPDATE

Мы забыли с вами про одно правило :)) PRG - Post-Redirect-Get :)
Про него можно прочитать тут: http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365146/Redirect-After-Post

Так что, работающий код вот он (я модальное окно не создавал, но вы на его закрытие повесьте событие и в нем удаляйте #myModal из адресной строки):

```
<!doctype>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type='text/javascript'>
     $(document).ready(function() {

        if(window.location.href.indexOf('myModal') > 0) {
            alert("Modal");
        }

    });
</script>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['trans'])) {
    if(isset($_POST["from_case"]) && $_POST["from_case"] != "") {
        $from_case = (float) htmlspecialchars($_POST["from_case"]);
        if ($from_case <= 100):
            /*операции*/
            header('Location: /test.php');
            exit;
        else: 
            header('Location: /test.php#myModal');
            exit;
        endif; 
        $from_case = 0;   
    }
}
else if (isset($_POST['transall'])) {
    /*другие операции*/
} 
?>
<form id="transferCase-form" action=""  method="post">
<p><input class="paidtext" type="text" id="bTC" placeholder="" name="from_case" /></p>
<p><input class="btn-cr" type="submit" value="Trans" id="transfetFrom" name="trans" /></p>
<p><input class="btn-cr" type="submit" value="Trans All" id="transfetFromAll" name="transall" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Добавил присвоение переменной $from_case. unset добавил, но ничего не изменилось. При обновлении страницы всегда всплывает модальное окно #myModal

Comment: Немного не так. Присвоение вы должны сделать после проверки на то, что такой элемнет есть в массиве $_POST. После этого, вы удаляете этот элемнет из массива пост и проверяете эту переменную на значение. Кстати, попробуйте распечатать ее перед проверкой.

Comment: $from_case все равно остается после обновления страницы.

Comment: А, извините, уже сам пропустил - эту переменную тоже надо обнулять. сейчас обновлю код.

Comment: Не понимаю, до сих пор переменная остается, хотя сделал как у вас

Comment: Так переменная остается, но она равна нулю. Вы в распечатке переменной какое значение видите?

Comment: То же значение, что и вводится в input, например, ввел 5000, вижу from_case: 5000

Comment: Тоесть, ваша проверка выглядит так:
`1. Вы вводите цифру 5000
2. Нажимаете отослать
3. Получаете окно с ошибкой.
4. Закрыли окно, перегрузили страницу и в импуте снова 5000?`

Comment: После перезагрузки окно  #myModal снова появляется, input пустой, а print выводит from_case: 5000

Comment: Странно... Вы не могли бы показать свой код на сервере? Так же: распечатайте еще и $_POST['from_case']

Comment: $_POST['from_case'] пустой

Comment: А попробуйте `$from_case = 0` поставить сразу после `endif;`

Comment: Смотрите обновленный код. Я там еще добавил проверку на то, что $_POST['from_case'] не равно пустому стрингу

Comment: Все так же, вообще ничего не меняется

Comment: Обновите в вопросе пожалуйста ваш код, надо глянуть как он выглядит.

Comment: Обновил код в вопросе

Comment: А где распечатка `print "<h1>from_case: ".$from_case."<h1>";` ? Вечером набросаю что-то подобное и тестану у себя. Что-то мы тут заморочались кажется...

Comment: Огромное спасибо) Это уже похоже на решение моей проблемы)